# Snakemake wildscard unexpected changed

Tags: snakemake

I'm a novice of Snakemake and I come across a bug that struggled me a lot. 
I have a wildcards like this:

```py
 rank = ['Kingdom', 'Phylum', 'Class', 'Order', 'Family', 'Genus', 'Species']
 ordi = ['DCA', 'CCA', 'RDA', 'NMDS', 'MDS', 'NMDS', 'PCoA']
```

The previous version didn't have the wildcards problem and run successfully

the previous version rule all like this:

```py
rule all:
  input:
    expand('common_taxonomic/abundance_table_{Rank}.biom', Rank = rank),
    directory('Gene/gene_Venn'),
    directory('Gene/gene_samples_heatmap'),
    directory('taxa_ternaryplot'),
    directory(expand('beta/PCA/{Rank}', Rank = rank))
  benchmark:
    "Check_utility.tsv"
```

But when I exchange the wildcards position like

```py
directory(expand('beta/{Rank}/PCA/', Rank = rank)),
directory(expand('beta/{Rank}/{Ordi}', Rank = rank, Ordi = ordi))
```

I got this error

```
Building DAG of jobs...
MissingInputException in line 59 of /sysdata/Meta/pipeline/Snakefile:
Missing input files for rule biom_convert:
common_taxonomic/Table_taxa_NR_Kingdom/CCA.txt
```

As you can see, the rank wildcard is elongated with /PCA, or /{ordi}. I am quite confused about this, am I writing a wrong code?

my biom_convert rule is:

```py
rule biom_convert:
  input: 'common_taxonomic/Table_taxa_NR_{rank}.txt'
  output:'common_taxonomic/abundance_table_{rank}.biom'
  shell:'biom convert -i {input} -o {output} --table-type="OTU table" --to-json'
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if we got the complete information required to solve it, but we can still try :).

The names of wildcards are completely arbitrary, and you can name them however you like. If you name your wildcard `rank` it is in no way related to the wildcards of other rules. In fact, what can be the value of wildcard `rank` in one rule, can be the wildcard value of `ordi` in another!

So what we will have to do is make sure that the output rule correctly distinguishes between rank and ordi:

```
rule biom_convert:
    input:
        'common_taxonomic/Table_taxa_NR_{rank}.txt'
    output:
        'common_taxonomic/abundance_table_{rank}/{ordi}.biom'
    shell:
        'biom convert -i {input} -o {output} --table-type="OTU table" --to-json'
```

If you want you can force the wildcards of `rank` and `ordi` through [global wildcard constraints](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#wildcards):

```
wildcard_constraints:
    rank='|'.join(rank)
    ordi='|'.join(ordi)
```

Now I am not sure if this will solve the complete problem you have, but it should definitely push you in the right direction.

Comment: Tanks for your advision, I solved this bug by delete the data and rerun, I have no idea how it works. but what I gonna actually do is to apply a rule whose output is an existing  directory generated by other parallel rules. Do you have some suggestions about it ?

Comment: Your question is way to broad for me to answer :)